# Akka - verify installation

Tags: scala, akka

I have installed Akka and need to verify whether the installation is successful. I simply used

```
akka -version
```

but this gave an error. What would be the reason? Does akka not supporting -version?
This is the error it is reporting

```
Starting Akka...
Running Akka 2.2.4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -version
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at akka.kernel.Main$$anonfun$1.apply(Main.scala:82)
    at akka.kernel.Main$$anonfun$1.apply(Main.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at akka.kernel.Main$.main(Main.scala:82)
    at akka.kernel.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka doesn't support the `-version` command. One way to find out if your installation works is running a simple [boot class](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/#akka.kernel.Bootable), as Akka suggests:

```
>  akka
No boot classes specified
Usage: bin/akka org.somewhere.BootClass
```